# Unable to use a closed cursor

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

After some operations on the `res.partner` model, I get this exception on the second time the make_po method is invoked. If I stop the server and restart it, the operation continues correctly following is my override of the make_po method and the stacktrace:

```
class procurement_order(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'procurement.order'

    counter = 0
    global_po_id = None
    line_counter = 0
    first_line = None
    def make_po(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        _logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        """ Resolve the purchase from procurement, which may result in a new PO creation, a new PO line creation or a quantity change on existing PO line.
        Note that some operations (as the PO creation) are made as SUPERUSER because the current user may not have rights to do it (mto product launched by a sale for example)
        @return: dictionary giving for each procurement its related resolving PO line.
        OVERRIDE: If we already have a purchase order on a draft state with the same product, do not append the lines.
        Instead create a new Purchase Order
        """
        company = self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr, uid, uid, context=context).company_id
        po_obj = self.pool.get('purchase.order')
        seq_obj = self.pool.get('ir.sequence')
        sales_orders = self.pool.get('sale.order')
        po_line = self.pool.get('purchase.order.line')

        # Get the procurement ID ("key" == Procurement ID, "value" == PO line)
        procurement_purchase_order = super(procurement_order, self).make_po(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
        key, value = procurement_purchase_order.popitem()
        procurement_purchase_order[key] = value

        # Search for the equivalent purchase.order.line
        p_o_line_returned_id = po_line.search(cr, uid, [('id', '=', value)])
        p_o_line_returned = po_line.browse(cr, uid, p_o_line_returned_id, context=context)

        # get purchase order from its line
        purchase_order_from_line_ID = po_obj.search(cr, uid, [('id', '=', p_o_line_returned.order_id.id)])
        purchase_order_from_line = po_obj.browse(cr, uid, purchase_order_from_line_ID, context=context)

        # Get me the current procurement
        current_procurement_ID = self.search(cr, uid, [('id', '=', key)])
        current_procurement = self.browse(cr, uid, current_procurement_ID, context=context)

        # Get me the line ids of the lines that are related to purchase_order_from_line_ID
        lines_IDS = po_line.search(cr, uid, [('order_id', '=', purchase_order_from_line_ID[0])])
        _logger.warning('lines_IDS' + str(lines_IDS))

        # Check the source of all the lines in thelines_IDS
        for line in po_line.browse(cr, uid, lines_IDS, context=context):
            _logger.warning('First line value ' + str(procurement_order.first_line))
            _logger.warning('')
            if line.procurement_ids != 0:
                if procurement_order.line_counter == 0:
                    procurement_order.first_line = line 
                    procurement_order.line_counter += 1

                    # Compare the first line procurement.group_id with the current procurement.group_id
                if procurement_order.first_line.procurement_ids and procurement_order.first_line.procurement_ids[0].group_id == current_procurement[0].group_id:
                    _logger.warning('GROUP IDS ARE EQUAL')
                else:
                    _logger.warning('GROUP IDS ARE NOT EQUAL')

                    # if we have inequality between the group ids then that means that the current "line" was created by a different SO
                    to_remove = []
                    to_remove.append(line.id)

                    # from the current_procurement.group_id get the PO.line and remove it
                    temp_group_id = current_procurement[0].group_id.id
                    _logger.warning(str(temp_group_id))
                    temp_line_for_removal_ID = po_line.search(cr, uid, [('id', '=', temp_group_id)])
                    po_line.unlink(cr, uid, temp_line_for_removal_ID, context=context)


                    _logger.warning('Removed from Purchase Order ' + str(purchase_order_from_line_ID[0]) + ' Lines ' + str(to_remove))
                    pass_ids = []
                    # for all the procrements that belong to my SO
                    # for procurement in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
                    partner = self._get_product_supplier(cr, uid, current_procurement, context=context)
                    if not partner:
                        self.message_post(cr, uid, [current_procurement.id], _('There is no supplier associated to product %s') % (current_procurement.product_id.name))
                        procurement_purchase_order[current_procurement.id] = False
                    else:
                        schedule_date = self._get_purchase_schedule_date(cr, uid, current_procurement, company, context=context)
                        purchase_date = self._get_purchase_order_date(cr, uid, current_procurement, company, schedule_date, context=context) 
                        line_vals = self._get_po_line_values_from_proc(cr, uid, current_procurement, partner, company, schedule_date, context=context)  # get the lines from here
                        name = seq_obj.get(cr, uid, 'purchase.order') or _('PO: %s') % current_procurement.name
                        po_vals = {
                        'name': name,
                        'origin': current_procurement.origin,
                        'partner_id': partner.id,
                        'location_id': current_procurement.location_id.id,
                        'picking_type_id': current_procurement.rule_id.picking_type_id.id,
                        'pricelist_id': partner.property_product_pricelist_purchase.id,
                        'currency_id': partner.property_product_pricelist_purchase and partner.property_product_pricelist_purchase.currency_id.id or current_procurement.company_id.currency_id.id,
                        'date_order': purchase_date.strftime(DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT),
                        'company_id': current_procurement.company_id.id,
                        'fiscal_position': po_obj.onchange_partner_id(cr, uid, None, partner.id, context=context)['value']['fiscal_position'],
                        'payment_term_id': partner.property_supplier_payment_term.id or False,
                        'dest_address_id': current_procurement.partner_dest_id.id,
                    }

                    # The first time create the PO and add a line to it
                    if procurement_order.counter == 0:
                        po_id = self.create_procurement_purchase_order(cr, uid, current_procurement, po_vals, line_vals, context=context)
                        procurement_order.global_po_id = po_id
                        po_line_id = po_obj.browse(cr, uid, po_id, context=context).order_line[0].id
                        pass_ids.append(current_procurement.id)
                        procurement_purchase_order[current_procurement.id] = po_line_id
                        self.write(cr, uid, [current_procurement.id], {'purchase_line_id': po_line_id}, context=context)
                        _logger.warning('New Purchase order created ' + str(po_id))
                    else:
                        # All the other lines from the procurements will be appended here
                        proc_order = self.pool.get('procurement.order')
                        purchase_order_created = po_obj.browse(cr, uid, procurement_order.global_po_id, context=context)  # get the Purchase Order
                        line_vals = proc_order._get_po_line_values_from_proc(cr, uid, current_procurement, partner, company, schedule_date, context=context)  # Get the line from the procurement
                        po_line_obj = self.pool.get('purchase.order.line')
                        line_vals['order_id'] = purchase_order_created[0].id
                        # if there exists a line with the same id, do not add it
                        if len(po_line_obj.search(cr, uid, [('order_id', '=', purchase_order_created[0].id)])) == 0:
                            po_line_id = po_line_obj.create(cr, uid, line_vals, context=context)
                            _logger.warning('Appending line ' + str(line_vals) + 'to existing Purchase order ' + str(purchase_order_created))
                        else:
                            _logger.warning('Line has already been appended, dismissed')
                    if pass_ids:
                        self.message_post(cr, uid, pass_ids, body=_("Draft Purchase Order created"), context=context)
                    procurement_order.counter += 1
        self.pool.get('purchase.order.line').split_lines(cr, uid, [procurement_purchase_order[ids[0]]], context=context)
        return procurement_purchase_order
```

Stacktrace:

```
2015-09-10 13:15:11,752 1167 ERROR odoov8 openerp.http: Exception during JSON request handling.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 537, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 574, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 310, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/service/model.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 307, in checked_call
    return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 803, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 403, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 948, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
    return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/addons/portal_sale/portal_sale.py", line 67, in action_button_confirm
    return super(sale_order, self).action_button_confirm(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/addons/sale/sale.py", line 605, in action_button_confirm
    self.signal_workflow(cr, uid, ids, 'order_confirm')
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 3560, in signal_workflow
    result[res_id] = workflow.trg_validate(uid, self._name, res_id, signal, cr)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/workflow/__init__.py", line 85, in trg_validate
    return WorkflowService.new(cr, uid, res_type, res_id).validate(signal)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/workflow/service.py", line 91, in validate
    res2 = wi.validate(signal)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/workflow/instance.py", line 75, in validate
    wi.process(signal=signal, force_running=force_running, stack=stack)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/workflow/workitem.py", line 120, in process
    ok = self._split_test(activity['split_mode'], signal, stack)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/workflow/workitem.py", line 248, in _split_test
    self._join_test(t[0], t[1], stack)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/workflow/workitem.py", line 257, in _join_test
    WorkflowItem.create(self.session, self.record, activity, inst_id, stack=stack)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/workflow/workitem.py", line 95, in create
    workflow_item.process(stack=stack)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/workflow/workitem.py", line 120, in process
    ok = self._split_test(activity['split_mode'], signal, stack)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/workflow/workitem.py", line 248, in _split_test
    self._join_test(t[0], t[1], stack)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/workflow/workitem.py", line 257, in _join_test
    WorkflowItem.create(self.session, self.record, activity, inst_id, stack=stack)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/workflow/workitem.py", line 95, in create
    workflow_item.process(stack=stack)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/workflow/workitem.py", line 120, in process
    ok = self._split_test(activity['split_mode'], signal, stack)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/workflow/workitem.py", line 248, in _split_test
    self._join_test(t[0], t[1], stack)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/workflow/workitem.py", line 257, in _join_test
    WorkflowItem.create(self.session, self.record, activity, inst_id, stack=stack)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/workflow/workitem.py", line 95, in create
    workflow_item.process(stack=stack)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/workflow/workitem.py", line 116, in process
    if not self._execute(activity, stack):
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/workflow/workitem.py", line 162, in _execute
    returned_action = self.wkf_expr_execute(activity)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/workflow/workitem.py", line 313, in wkf_expr_execute
    return self.wkf_expr_eval_expr(activity['action'])
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/workflow/workitem.py", line 291, in wkf_expr_eval_expr
    result = eval(line, env, nocopy=True)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/tools/safe_eval.py", line 314, in safe_eval
    return eval(c, globals_dict, locals_dict)
  File "", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 239, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 547, in new_api
    result = method(self._model, cr, uid, self.ids, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/addons/sale/sale.py", line 765, in action_ship_create
    procurement_obj.run(cr, uid, proc_ids, context=context)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/addons/procurement_jit_stock/procurement_jit_stock.py", line 30, in run
    res = super(procurement_order, self).run(cr, uid, ids, autocommit=autocommit, context=context)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/addons/stock/procurement.py", line 219, in run
    self.pool.get('stock.move').action_confirm(cr, uid, move_to_confirm_ids, context=context)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/addons/stock/stock.py", line 2214, in action_confirm
    self._create_procurements(cr, uid, moves, context=context)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/addons/procurement_jit_stock/procurement_jit_stock.py", line 43, in _create_procurements
    self.pool['procurement.order'].run(cr, uid, res, context=context)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/addons/procurement_jit_stock/procurement_jit_stock.py", line 30, in run
    res = super(procurement_order, self).run(cr, uid, ids, autocommit=autocommit, context=context)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/addons/stock/procurement.py", line 210, in run
    res = super(procurement_order, self).run(cr, uid, new_ids, autocommit=autocommit, context=context)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/addons/procurement/procurement.py", line 206, in run
    res = self._run(cr, uid, procurement, context=context or {})
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/addons/purchase/purchase.py", line 1267, in _run
    return self.make_po(cr, uid, [procurement.id], context=context)[procurement.id]
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/addons/glints/models/purchase.py", line 154, in make_po
    if procurement_order.first_line.procurement_ids and procurement_order.first_line.procurement_ids[0].group_id == current_procurement[0].group_id:
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/fields.py", line 817, in __get__
    self.determine_value(record)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/fields.py", line 910, in determine_value
    record._prefetch_field(self)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 239, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 3231, in _prefetch_field
    result = records.read(list(fnames), load='_classic_write')
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 239, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 3176, in read
    self._read_from_database(stored, inherited)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 239, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 3300, in _read_from_database
    cr.execute(query_str, [tuple(sub_ids)] + where_params)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/openerp/sql_db.py", line 157, in wrapper
    raise psycopg2.OperationalError(msg)
OperationalError: Unable to use a closed cursor.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume it is because you are misusing the Odoo ORM.  Firstly in Odoo you never declare class level properties like these...

```
counter = 0
global_po_id = None
line_counter = 0
first_line = None
```

And then you refer to it here:

```
if procurement_order.first_line
```

The problem is procurement_order is of type osv.osv but this line of code should be using a browse record.  As it attempts to follow the trail and lazily load the data items from what it thinks is a browse record, it gets to a point when it needs to use a cursor and it hasn't got one to use, hence the error.

It is best to think of the osv.osv class as a read-only meta class that describes your table in the database but also lets you have some static or class methods defined.

The procurement_order you use should be the result of a browse.

```
my_procurement_order = self.browse(cr, uid, ids[0], context=context)
```

The next problem is you can't assign values like first_line to a browse record at run time, they are read-only (NB this changes in Odoo 8 new API but that is another story).

A common practice here is to maintain something like a local dictionary that you can refer to:

first_lines = {my_procurement_order.id: a_line}